# How transfer a specific secondary key, if I have two of them?

Tags: tarantool

How in `alter()` transfer a specific secondary key, if I have two secondary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the required index like this:

```
box.space.space_name.index.<index name>:alter(...)
```

Instead of `<index name>` specify the index you want to alter.